# gulp, проблемы с подключением пакетов с другого проекта

Tags: gulp

Я перенес с 1-го проекта во 2-ой проект файлы:
gulpfile.js
package.json
После чего в терминале прописал npm i, установка вроде прошла, но возникли проблемы. Что я сделал не так?

gulpfile.js

```js
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass        = require('gulp-sass');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('server', function() {

    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)")
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix: ''}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)", gulp.parallel('styles'));
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles'));
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "pulse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.5",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

[image: Терминал]

Comment: Пробовали по иснтуркции сделать? [инстуркция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460213/14135825) у вас ошибка с правами

Comment: Не помогло ничего.

Comment: Пробовали включить другой терминал? Пробовали VScode с правами админа запустить?

Answer (score 0):

Установите `gulp` глобально:

```
npm i -g gulp
```